# Added bullet point of international experience to resume

Tags: resume, work-experience, international

Good afternoon,
Working on my resume and I have recently flew to the middle east to work alongside the customer providing technical training. I want to include this in a bullet point in my resume under a KEY QUALIFICATIONS section as I am frequently told that international experience is great for resumes as it shows that you are culturally aware and willing to travel to far locations. How would I word this in as few words as possible?

Overall description:

**Provided technical training and expertise to engineers in the UAE over the span of 6 months**

I currently have :

- International experience training customer engineers

This doesn't seem to be worded as an "attractive" key qualification.

I am not sure how to provide this in as few words as possible to the top of my resume. I would elaborate more down below under my experience section this KEY QUALIFICATIONS section is to hopefully attract the eye of whoever is reviewing the resume to want to read more.

Comment: it's a bit of a subjective question, but I think I'd use your overall description - it is concise and usefully descriptive.

Comment: Rory, thank you very much. If you post that as an answer I would gladly accept it.

Comment: To me, "international experience" means that you have experience working in companies in different countries. In that case your employment history will show this experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your shortened version

- International experience training customer engineers

doesn't really tell me much. I'd suggest the overall description you gave:

- Provided technical training and expertise to engineers in the UAE over the span of 6 months

Is much better - it's still concise, and is a useful description. It will help an interviewer have a better idea of what questions to ask.